# Creating new bitmap from template and preserve template bitmap parameters

Tags: c#, bitmap

I want to create a deep clone of a bitmap.

Therefore I tried the following:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(uTemplateImage);
```

This wouldn't preserve the PixelFormat.

Then I tried

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(uTemplateImage.Width ,uTemplateImage.Height ,uTemplateImage.PixelFormat);
```

This wouldn't preserve the HorizontalVertical and VerticalResolution.

What would be the way to create a bitmap with the same parameters as template bitmap?

Edit: It was suggested that I should use .Clone().

However, that doesn't work for me:

```
new Bitmap b = uTemplateImage.Clone();
```

The compiler tells me "There's no overload for Bitmap that would accept 0 arguments.

If I use

```
 Bitmap b = uTemplateImage.Clone();
```

it tells me that object can't be explicitely converted to Bitmap.

This is the code:

```
    private Bitmap ProcessImage(Bitmap uTemplateImage,Bitmap uIntruderImage)
    {
        // set up Dlib facedetectors and shapedetectors
        using (var fd = FrontalFaceDetector.GetFrontalFaceDetector())
        using (var sp = new ShapePredictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"))
        {
            // convert image to dlib format
            var imgTemplate = uTemplateImage.ToArray2D<RgbPixel>();

            // find faces in image
            var facesInTemplateImage = fd.Detect(imgTemplate);
            var TemplateRect = facesInTemplateImage[0];

            // get landmark points
            var TemplateShape = sp.Detect(imgTemplate, TemplateRect);
            var TemplatePoints = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, (int)TemplateShape.Parts)
                              let p = TemplateShape.GetPart((uint)i)
                              select new OpenCvSharp.Point(p.X, p.Y)).ToArray();

            new Bitmap b = uTemplateImage.Clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to clone it, just use the `Clone()` method of the `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap b = uTemplateImage.Clone();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have edited my post to show that. Also, without the "new", it tells me that "object can't be explcititely converted to Bitmap".

Comment: what is the type of `uTemplateImage`? because from the questions I got the implication that it is a Bitmap.

Comment: and is this `Bitmap` class is the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class? because if it is, `Clone()` won't necessarily need  parameters.

Comment: I'll need to check everything. Thanks so far.